# nested cloudformation get vpcid on vpc creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Following several threads on SO and aws forums, I am trying to get a basic nested cloudformation example working.

The `ChildStack01` creates a VPC, then `ChildStack02` adds a subnet. but after trying several combinations I get the same type of error, `Output 'VpcID' not found in stack`

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",


    "Resources": {
       "ChildStack01": {
           "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
           "Properties": {
               "TemplateURL": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cf-templates-1u1ziwem31f87-eu-west-1/xxx",
               "TimeoutInMinutes": "60"


            }
       },
       "ChildStack02": {
           "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
           "Properties": {
               "TemplateURL": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cf-templates-1u1ziwem31f87-eu-west-1/yyy",
               "Parameters": {
                  "VpcId" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ChildStack01", "Outputs.VpcID" ] }
               },
               "TimeoutInMinutes": "60"
           }
       }
   }
```

I have tried adding a parameter with

```
"VPC" : {
      "Description" : "VPC ID",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
    }
```

but then generates an error as there is no reference value for VPC listed in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html

Is there a basic way to get the VPC-id after it has been created?

thanks
Art

Answer (score 3):

You should look at Exports.

In your VPC stack, create an Export section:

```
Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: Unique-VpcId
```

You can then import that value in another stack:

```
  VpcId:
    Fn::ImportValue: Unique-VpcId
```

You should of course include some way of generating unique export names (they have to be unique within a region) rather than hard-coding as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

In CF Template create `VPC`, use as below:

```
"Resources": {
    "VPC": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        ....
      }
    }
  },
"Outputs": {
    "VPC": {
      "Description": "VPC",
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "VPC"
      },
      "Export": {
        "Name": {
          "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-VPC"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In CF Template that you want to use output of 1st CF Template, as:

```
  "Parameters": {
        "VPCStackName": {
            "Description": "Name of VPC CF Stack",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "SOME_NAME"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
    "Subnet1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Fn::ImportValue": {
            "Fn::Sub": "${VPCStackName}-VPC"
          }
        },
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Ref": "CidrBlockSubnet1"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Ref": "AZ_NAME"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```